# Keep running out of water when doing a load of laundry specifically

Tags: plumbing, well-pump

I have a private well. I have no idea when pump was put in. Only lived in the house for about 6 years. As of recently I’ve been running out of water when only doing laundry. Well pump was also short cycling and cycling periodically when no water was being ran. Plumber came and told me toilet was leaking, fixed it and problem still persisted.

Water pressure by the tank reading 30 psi. Tank was reading 28 psi. I turned off water to the house and emptied tank. Psi on the tank was reading 11. Pressure switch is a 30/50. I think the tank is about 25 years old. Shook the tank and don’t hear any water moving around inside. No water coming out of shrader valve at the top of the tank. Pressure tank is an amtrol champion serial #cm3008

Yesterday, I found a leak underneath my kitchen sink. Replaced the leaking valve, emptied tank and filled it up to 28 psi where it should be. When system is pressurized and on the tank is reading 45 psi. Pump is no longer short cycling. It cycled for a little over a minute. Did another load of laundry and ran out of water again.

I have no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have a shallow well and an above-ground jet pump because otherwise you might not be aware of short cycling.

Your water table may have fallen, especially if your area is in a drought. Your pump may be worn out and needs to be rebuilt or replaced. The strainer at the bottom of the well may be clogged with grit. Your water-bearing stratum underground may be silted up from long use and needs to be re-developed. Or the stratum may be clogged with minerals which need to be dissolved with chemicals.

If you actually have a drilled, deep well with a submersible pump, there is a different set of possibilities.

I think you need a well company, not a plumber, on-site, hands-on to evaluate your well situation.

Meanwhile, since you're only running out of water when doing laundry, you can adjust the hot and cold water valves that supply the washing machine to reduce the rate at which the washer fills up. This is a temporary fix to give you a little time to find a well company.